# Angular. Why filter invokes automatically?

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I'm new in angular and I reeding A.Freeman's book "Pro Angular JS". 
So I stuck in one of examples trying to understand why filter in ng-repeat is triggered.
Here is the code:

```
<body ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default row" ng-controller="productListCtrl">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a ng-click="selectCategory()" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">Home</a>
            <a ng-repeat="item in data.products | orderBy:'category' | unique:'category'" ng-click="selectCategory(item)" class=" btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">
         {{item}}
         </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="well" ng-repeat="item in data.products | filter:categoryFilterFn">
                <h3>
                    <strong>{{item.name}}</strong>
                    <span class="pull-right label label-primary">
         {{item.price | currency}}
         </span>
                </h3>
                <span class="lead">{{item.description}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
    .controller("productListCtrl", function ($scope, $filter) {
        var selectedCategory = null;
        $scope.selectCategory = function (newCategory) {
            selectedCategory = newCategory;
        }
        $scope.categoryFilterFn = function (product) {
            return selectedCategory == null ||
                product.category == selectedCategory;
        }
    });
```

`categoryFilterFn` is one that confuses me. Why it's invoking when I press catefory buttons (with `selectCategory()` method on `ng-click`) since I never call `categoryFilterFn` explicitly?

Comment: Post your code as code, not as images.

Comment: Can't see images behind firewall.

Comment: Ok, I replaced images. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering you question - because of $digest. You don't have call categoryFilterFn directly. Your selectedCategory has changed which is used in categoryFilterFn and categoryFilterFn is bound to scope.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how I can describe it correctly but here my explanation.

There are two "independent" parts :

1. The repeat iterate over an array of items.
2. If you select an category via ng-click function you set the new category in the scope.

Here kicks the filter function in, witch ties it up. 
It is triggered because a new category is selected ($digest) and "reordering" the array (like map function in plain Javascript) and the angular magic (ng-repeat) displays only items with this category.

And that's the reason why I love angular so much