# Angular - How do I filter objects depending on id within a ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, filter, laravel-5.3

I got 3 types of product groups:

- Import (product_group_id value = 1)
- Export (product_group_id value = 2)
- Non-EU (product_group_id value = 3)

Each group contains products. I can determine to which product group each product belongs within my product create.

Now, I'm summing up these products in a product index. I do this with a `ng-repeat` and I'm suppose to be filtering the products depending on the product_group_id, like so:

```
<div style="display: inline;" class="btn-group">

    <a href="/products/export" type="submit" 
    class="{{ $product_group_id == 1 ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-default' }}" 
    role="button">@lang('product.export')</a>

    <a href="/products/import" type="submit" 
    class="{{ $product_group_id == 2 ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-default' }}" 
    role="button">@lang('product.import')</a>

    <a href="/products/non-eu" type="submit" 
    class="{{ $product_group_id == 3 ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-default' }}" 
    role="button">@lang('product.non_eu')</a>

</div>


<table class="table table-hover product-table" ng-controller="ProductCtrl">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>@lang('product.name')</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="products in product | filter:SearchProduct" ng-cloak>

            <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id" class="checkbox" 
            value="@{{product.id}}"></td>

            <td><a href="@{{ url('/products/' . product_id) }}">
            @{{product.id}}</a></td>  

            <td><a ng-href="/products/@{{ product.id }}">
            @{{product.name | uppercase}}</a></td> 

        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

**ProductService.js:**

```
.controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/api/product')
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.products = response;
    });

});
```

I set my product_group_id to 1, 2 and 3 in my controller.

Every time I create a new `$product`, it'll display in every filter ('/products/import', '/products/export' and '/products/non-eu').

So, my question is, how do I filter my products on `$product_group_id` within my `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Can you post sample data of "product"? And also how you are getting "SearchProduct" variable?

Comment: With 'SearchProduct', I'm refering to my search form.

Answer (score 0):

Check the example on the **[filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)** page. Use an object, and set the `product_id` property

```
Search by product_id: <input type="text" ng-model="SearchProduct.product_id">
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:SearchProduct">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the ProductCtrl?

Is $product_group_id really defined with $scope.$product_group_id

And do you set the $product_group_id with your routes?

Normally you don't need any routes here only if you want to make it bookmark able.

Here is an similar question with an valid approach but without routes : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41270508/4189910)

Beside that:

```
<a href="@{{ url('/products/' . product_id) }}">
```

Use ng-href here

**Edit**:
you doing this with an very complicated approach. To answer your question :

```
<a ng-click="$product_group_id=1" type="submit" 
class="{{ $product_group_id == 1 ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-default' }}" 
role="button">@lang('product.export')</a>

<a ng-click="$product_group_id=2" type="submit" 
class="{{ $product_group_id == 2 ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-default' }}" 
role="button">@lang('product.import')</a>

<a  ng-click="$product_group_id=3" type ="submit" 
class="{{ $product_group_id == 3 ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-default' }}" 
role="button">@lang('product.non_eu')</a>
```

Your repeat :

```
    <tr ng-repeat="products in product | filter:SearchProductFn" ng-cloak>
```

your controller :

```
.controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.SearchProductFn = function(product) {
        return product.group.id == $product_group_id && product.name == $scope.SearchName;
     } 
    $http.get('/api/product')
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.products = response;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/BfWr1Wr38OGWlQDpGlBg?p=preview) very basic example, the gist of it below:

```
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-xs" type="button" placeholder="Search" ng-click="myFilter = {product_group_id: 1}">Group 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs" type="button" placeholder="Search" ng-click="myFilter = {product_group_id: 2}">Group 2</button>    
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <table id="results" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Brand</th>
          <th>PG</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:myFilter ">
          <td id="productName">{{product.productName}}</td>
          <td id="brand">{{product.brand}}</td>
          <td id="product_group_id">{{product.product_group_id}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you add a button that filters all products with a PG of 1 or 2?

Comment: Sure thing, see updated answer and [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BfWr1Wr38OGWlQDpGlBg?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

To filter by specific fields you can;

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{product_group_id: SearchProduct}" ng-cloak></tr>
```

This allows filtering on specific fields that you use in the filter:{} object.

Hope it helps!